# Find the NW vertex of a polygon

Tags: qgis, python, vector-grid, nodes

I am using QGIS 2.18 and I am wondering how to find the NW corner of a polygon and create an attribute of that point number. See the attached image.

[image]

For example, please node 8 is the NW corner for Grid #1, 13 is the NW corner for Grid 5 and so on.  any help with this would be wonderful. The two files I am working with is

```
Grid = 'grid'
```

and

```
Vertex = 'nodes'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**QGIS 2.18.20**

(Latest QGIS versions have issues with Virtual Layer)

Add a `Virtual Layer` with below syntax:

```
SELECT grid.*, nodes.id
FROM   grid, nodes
WHERE  st_touches(grid.geometry, nodes.geometry) = 1                  -- (1)
       AND
       st_x(nodes.geometry)-st_x(st_centroid(grid.geometry)) < 0      -- (2)
       AND
       st_y(nodes.geometry)-st_y(st_centroid(grid.geometry)) > 0      -- (3)
```

Footnotes:

The idea is really simple. As you need northwest corner, the x coordinate at the vertex is less, while the y is greater, than the centroid of the polygon.

(1) This helps to choose touching four corner points around each polygon.

(2) x-difference (dx) between the anticipated node and the centroid becomes negative.

(3) y-difference (dy) between the anticipated node and the centroid becomes positive.

[image]

So, if you want to find NE corner, (2) should be `>0`.

Comment: what are the needed attributes in each layer to make this work?  worked but not sure how it did it and would like to work my way through understanding it.

Comment: i get this error when adding the virtual layerLayer is not valid: The layer ?query=SELECT%20grid.*,%20nodes.id%0AFROM%20%20%20grid,%20nodes%0AWHERE%20%20st_touches(grid.geometry,%20nodes.geometry)%20%3D%201%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AND%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20st_x(nodes.geometry)-st_x(st_centroid(grid.geometry))%20%3C%200%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AND%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20st_y(nodes.geometry)-st_y(st_centroid(grid.geometry))%20%3E%200 is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map

Comment: to claify in the nodes layer i have a attribute of "Node_Id" and in the grid layer i have a attribute of  "Grid_ID"

Comment: @lowsparked Added some explanation with picture. If your nodes layer has `"Node_ID"`, then the first line would be  `SELECT grid.*, nodes.Node_Id`.

Comment: that settles that .. I owe you a beer! Thank you so much for helping me understand how it all came about!

Comment: No worries @lowsparked and Thanks for your follow-up comments. I'm glad it worked :)

Comment: Again thank you for your help but it seems now that if the grid is tilted at all it comes up with the two most NW points on the grid not just the most NW point?  I have screenshots i will update mo first post with

Comment: @lowsparked I understand what you mean, but will you open a new question? It will require substantial change to the logic in an answer.

Comment: the rotated poly question has been asked here:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296916/find-the-nw-vertex-of-a-rotated-polygon  Thanks again for all your help