# Find the NW vertex of a rotated polygon

Tags: polygon, vertices

I am using QGIS 2.18 and I am wondering how to find the NW corner of a polygon and create an attribute of that point number. See the attached image.[image]
For example, please node 8 is the NW corner for Grid #1, 13 is the NW corner for Grid 5 and so on. any help with this would be wonderful. The two files I am working with is

Grid = 'grid' 
and

Vertex = 'nodes' (Bold)

Comment: Where should I see nodes 8 and 13?

Comment: to the left.  but the name of the node is not all that important

Comment: Not so much but I would like to be sure where it is.

Comment: nodes are labelled east to west, Thaks for asking for clarification, every little bit helps is asking a question.

Comment: relevant here: http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-create-points-at-corners-of-polygon-with-arcpy/

Answer (score 2):

How do you define NW corner? Does the image below have NW corner at all?

[image]

Comment: 2 would be the NW corner,  draw a line down the middle of the polygon east to west and what is the most NW corner.  for this one 2 and 3 are the two most north points and 2 is the further west most point

Comment: Call your points differently. Hard to imagine point 2 being north west. +1 for answer.

Comment: not sure what you mean by calling your points differently?

Comment: I agree with @FelixIP. NW is very well known compass direction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Compass_Rose_English_North.svg and it points to 315° N. What you are after is something else.

Comment: @lowsparked according to what you proposed here, you've got to implement a rule, as results will most likely be inconsistend for different border cases; *get the two northern-most points and the western-most of those* could be one, another could be *find the NW point of the **bbox** and get the nearest vertex to that point*...which would yield different, but consistent and directionally weighted results.

Answer (score 2):

Having seen ongoing discussions about how to define "NW", I am not sure if this is valid answer.

[image]

The idea here is to calculate the azimuth between the nodes and the polygon centroid, then to find the most closest to NW (315 degrees) direction.

**QGIS 2.18.20** (probably 2.18.21, too)

```
  SELECT grid.*, 
         nodes.Node_Id, 
         abs(degrees(st_azimuth(st_centroid(grid.geometry), nodes.geometry))- 315) AS D
    FROM grid, nodes
   WHERE st_touches(grid.geometry, nodes.geometry) = 1    
GROUP BY grid.id
ORDER BY abs(degrees(st_azimuth(st_centroid(grid.geometry), nodes.geometry))- 315) ASC 
   LIMIT 1
```

If you want to find NE corner, change 315 to 45.

NB. This does not give solution when the rectangle lies lateral to NE line (45-deg) and corner nodes are located at equi-distance.

Answer (score 0):

I have code that I think you can modify, if all your rectangles are simple like above you need to get rotation, I would do this by average the azimuth of the short sides and long sides then find the nearest azimuth to 0 and then get the rotation. After that the logic below should work with some modification, I use this to find the NEWS sides of land sections.

I don't use QGIS so all these are arcpy methods, I only cursors and geometry so should be able to translate.

This returns azimuth for line segment.

```
def returnAzimuth(shape):
    point1 = shape.firstPoint
    point2 = shape.lastPoint
    dX = point2.X-point1.X
    dY = point2.Y-point1.Y
    az = math.atan2(dX,dY)*180/math.pi
    if az<0:
        az = az+360
        return az
    return az
```

This function takes a feature class or shapefile and finds the width angle and length angle of the rectangle.

```
def getTractSideRatio(landpolyshape):
distances = []
area = landpolyshape.area
if area:
    pnts= pnts = landpolyshape.getPart(0)
    distance = 0
    for x in range(pnts.count-2):
        if distance==0: distance = returnInverse(pnts.getObject(x),pnts.getObject(x+1))[1]
        az1=returnInverse(pnts.getObject(x),pnts.getObject(x+1))[0]
        az2=returnInverse(pnts.getObject(x+1),pnts.getObject(x+2))[0]
        length = returnInverse(pnts.getObject(x+1),pnts.getObject(x+2))[1]
        topaz = returnInverse(pnts.getObject(x),pnts.getObject(x+1))[0]+2
        lowaz = returnInverse(pnts.getObject(x),pnts.getObject(x+1))[0]-2          
        if az2 <= topaz and az2 >= lowaz:
            distance = distance + length
            if x==pnts.count-2 : distances.append(distance)
        else:
            distances.append(distance)
            distance = 0
    length = max(distances)
    width = area/length
    w2 = width/2
    l2 = length/2
    widthangle = 2*int(round(math.degrees(math.atan2(w2, l2))))
    lengthangle = 2*int(round(math.degrees(math.atan2(l2, w2))))
return widthangle,lengthangle
```

This function return inverse from 2 points

```
def returnInverse(point1,point2):
    dX = point2.X-point1.X
    dY = point2.Y-point1.Y
    dis = sqrt(dX**2+dY**2)
    az = math.atan2(dX,dY)*180/math.pi
    if az<0:
        az = az+360
        return az,dis
    return az,dis
```

I have modified  this to find the cardinal direction of the points of the polygon from the polygon center, you  will need to provide the rotation angle for this to be accurate.

```
from math import sqrt

def getNEWSByAzimuth(landPoly,rot):
    sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(6578)
    widthangle,lengthangle = getTractSideRatio(landPoly)
    if widthangle and lengthangle:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(landPoly.name,["SHAPE@"],spatial_reference=sr) as sc:
            for row in sc:
                polyShape=row[0]
                pnts = polyShape.getPart(0)
                for pnt in pnts:
                    polyCenter = polyShape.centroid
                    linetopoint = pnt
                    az=returnInverse(polyCenter,pnt)[0]
                    az = az + rot
                    if az>360:
                        az=az-360                 
                    if az < 360 and az >= 360 - lengthangle/2: #this sets the ratio for the rectangle lengthangle/2
                        side="NORTH"
                        print(side)
                    if az <= 0 + lengthangle/2  and az >= 0:
                        side="NORTH"
                        print(side)
                    if az < 270 + widthangle/2 and az >= 270 - widthangle/2:
                        side="WEST"
                        print(side)
                    if az < 180 + lengthangle/2 and az >= 180 - lengthangle/2:
                        side="SOUTH"
                        print(side)
                    if az > 90 - widthangle/2 and az < 90 + widthangle/2:
                        side="EAST"
                        print(side)
```